# wrong params in url with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, parameters

Here is my url : `/creations/stock?id=3`

When I click to my link `creations_stock_path(:id => creation.id)` I have an error `Couldn't find Creation with id=stock`. I really don't understand the problem, I have the same for another object (products) and it works.

When I check what are send with my params, I have

```
>> params
=> {"id"=>"stock", "action"=>"show", "controller"=>"creations"}
```

Why ??? In my controller, I wrote :

```
def stock
  @creation = Creation.find(params[:id])
end
```

So I don't understand first why rails want to use Show action and also why my params are wrong...

Any idea ?

Edit : My routes.rb file :

```
get "creations/stock"
get "products/stock"
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means that there's no `Creation` record in the database that has an id equal to `params[:id]`.  Check your db to see if the record exists.  This exception shows a 404 page when running in production mode or at least when `config.consider_all_requests_local` is false.

If you don't want it to raise an exception, try `find_by_id` instead which will return `nil` when the record is not found.

Comment: In fact it was because my get "creations/stock" was AFTER `resources :creations` in my route.rb file. I didn't know that it was mandatory to be before. I just lost half an hour for... nothing.

Comment: If that's the issue, then it's better to just add a block to `resources :creations` and add `get :stock, on: :collection` in the block. that way, it won't conflict with the show action and you don't have to worry about hierarchy in your routes.